# Accidently deleted opt/ folder missing lib librh-php72-php7.so

Tags: yum, httpd, php7

I accidentally deleted my opt folder. By reinstalling the missing software, i get most of the stuff running. However  `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/librh-php72-php7.so` is still missing for httpd and reinstalling `rh-php72-php` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reinstall the package containing the missing file.

```
yum reinstall /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/librh-php72-php7.so
```

Comment: When trying install the lib comes the error no matching argument, aka lib seams not found for install

Comment: @Yann Is that the correct path? Does the package even exist anymore? Maybe it was removed. That is an old unsupported version of PHP.

Comment: yes it should I installed it last week, this is the pakage site https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/rh-php72-php-7.2.10-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Got it was wrong path

Comment: Nextcloud gives the wrong path in the tutorial, I don't know how I did it las week

Comment: Thx for your help